# How to combine an javabean with jquery validation plugin?

Tags: java, jquery, web-applications, jquery-validate

I am building a web app where users can sign up. I have a jquery validation method for the signup form. 
What I need is to also validate the username for availability according to my database.
I am not allowed to use php to do this, so i need to use java, a javabean for that cause.
How can i combine jquery and java like this ? Should i use the "remote" command from jquery or combine validation with another function ? 
If name already exists n database i don't want my form to submit.

**Signup.xhtml**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss.css" />
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
         <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
        <script src="validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container" align="center">
        <h2>User Registration</h2>
        <form action="welcome.xhtml" method="post" id="contact_form">

            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name"/>
                <span id="nameInfo"></span>
            </div>

            <div >
                <label for="email" >Email</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" name="email"/>
                <span id="emailInfo"></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="password">password</label>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="pass1"/>
                <span id="pass1Info"></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="confirm">confirm password</label>
                <input id="confirm" type="password" name="pass2"/>
                <span id="pass2Info"></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message"/>
                <span id="messageInfo"></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input id="send" name="send"  type="submit" value="Send"/>
            </div>

            <br/>
<!--            <p>Already registered? <a href="/login">Sign in</a>.</p>        -->
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**validate.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Validation rules for form
    $("#contact_form").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
//                remote: ???
            },

            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },

            confirm: {
                required: true,
                equalto: "#password"
            },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name",

            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },

            confirm:{
                equalto: "Passwords are not matching"
            },

            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

CheckAvailability.java (I inserted as js, cause it would not retain its format)

```js
package Beans;  

import java.io.*;  
import java.sql.*;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  

public class CheckAvailability extends HttpServlet {  

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -734503860925086969L;  

 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
        doPost(request, response);  
    }  

 @Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  


        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        try {  

            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teddb"; // teddb is my database name  
            Connection connection;  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "Sk1994!!");  


            String uname = request.getParameter("name");  

            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select username from users where username=?");  
            ps.setString(1,uname);  
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();  

            if (!rs.next()) {  
                out.println("");  
            }  
            else{  
                out.println("Username already in use");  
            }  
            out.println();  

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException ex) {  
            out.println("Error ->" + ex.getMessage());  
        } finally {  
            out.close();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: If the question is *"should I use the  `remote` method for this"*, then the answer is simply "yes".

Comment: `remote` does not require PHP or any particular server language.  It's simply looking for a response from the server in JSON format.  In PHP, that would be an `echo json_encode("response")`.  Use whatever equivalent Java commands.

Comment: I was pretty sure about the remote. Yeah, i 've read about the json repsponse elsewhere too. My problem is that i haven't found a solid example on how a java bean should be called in the url of remote, what should the java return and how to use what is returned in the success section

Comment: *"how to use what is returned"* ~ you don't.  that's automatically handled by the plugin.  *"how a java bean should be called in the url of remote"* ~ the same way you'd call any server-side script via URL.  *"what should the java return"* ~ as already stated... a JSON encoded response.  `true` to pass validation and `false` to fail validation.  Any string would fail validation and the string becomes the error message.